# Sending newlines inside string through TCPclient

Tags: c#, .net

Trying to send a string containing a number of newline characters between words using TCPclient and C# where the newline characters needs to stay intact...

Working c++ example is here:

```
TCPClient->IOHandler->DefStringEncoding = enUTF8;
TCPClient->IOHandler->WriteLn("write text");
TCPClient->IOHandler->WriteLn("Test\n\n\nTest");
```

With this code the string shows up in the servers textfield the way I want: Test\n\n\nTest

But when trying c#:

```
clientStreamWriter.WriteLine("write text");
clientStreamWriter.WriteLine("Test\n\n\nTest");
```

This string shows up in the server textfield as: Test
Then the server returns a unknown command response... Seems as the StreamWriter breaks the string at the newline character and sends the rest as a new string and the server expects a new command.

How can I prevent this from happening? I have no idea what the server code is and writing in c++ is not an option for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your server protocol; you'll need to change the server to fix it. [You need message framing.](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/message-framing.html)

Comment: The server is 3rd party and I have no access to source code unfortunately. But since it works with the above c++ example and also through telnet I should also be able to get it to work with c# ?

Comment: The server is **broken**; you should lean on the vendor to fix it. It just *happens* to work sometimes. That said, SLaks posted an answer that may work - set `AutoFlush` to `false`, then call `Flush` after each `WriteLine` call. Please note that you are *not* fixing the problem; you're just hoping to avoid it. The server is still wrong, and **will** still fail once other factors come into play (other processes swapping in/out of memory, routers in-between the client/server are changed, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just split your string up and send it as seperate calls ...

assuming your client is smart enough to figure out / your protocol defines an end messsage in some way?

```
TCPClient->IOHandler->DefStringEncoding = enUTF8;
TCPClient->IOHandler->WriteLn("write text");
TCPClient->IOHandler->WriteLn("[[begin]]");
TCPClient->IOHandler->WriteLn("Test");
TCPClient->IOHandler->WriteLn("");
TCPClient->IOHandler->WriteLn("");
TCPClient->IOHandler->WriteLn("");
TCPClient->IOHandler->WriteLn("Test");
TCPClient->IOHandler->WriteLn("[[end]]");
```